# Creating a similarity measure that is weighted by column range

Tags: r, matrix, similarity

Consider the following matrix:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), X2 = c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 6L), X3 = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L), X4 = c(2L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 8L), X5 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Each column corresponds to a respondent and each line contains the rank number that respondents assigned to a specific object. Notice that the range of the ranking may be different from respondent to respondent.

I am trying to create a similarity measure that weights distances based on the range of each column. **Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
m <- test
d <- dist(m, "manhattan", diag=FALSE, upper=TRUE)/nrow(m) 
maxmin <- max(m, na.rm=TRUE) - min(m,na.rm=TRUE)
WeightedAgreement <- as.matrix((-1 * d + maxmin) / maxmin)
```

With this measure, the distance between X1 and X3 = 0.761 since ((1.666 * - 1)+7)/7 = 0.761.

The problem with my formula is that it is using the range of all values in the table -- thus "maxmin" is always 7, which biases the calculation of similarities. I need to use the range of the columns rather than the table when calculating similarities. The maxmin value of columns 1 and 3 should be 4 (5-1) and the similarity between X1 and X3 should be 0.583.

Comment: Instead of just showing the output of `test` just type `dput(test)` and it will give you a version that we can just cut and paste into R.

Comment: `maxmin <-  apply(m, 2, function(x){max(x) - min(x)})`  will give you the columnwise range. as will `apply(m, 2, function(x){diff(range(x,na.rm = T))})`.

Comment: Also, I think you mean that the maxmin values of columns 1 and *2* should be 4. The value for column 3 is 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. That almost worked. There is still a problem: maxmin is considering the values of only one of the columns being compared. For instance, the distance between X1 and X4 is =((1.8333 * - 1)+3)/3. The value 3 comes from the fact that max(X4)-min(X4) = 3. But notice that max(X1)-min(X1) = 4. So in order to compare X1 and X4 I would need max(X1, X4)-min(X1, X4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to define `maxmin` as follows:

```
maxmin <- outer(names(m), names(m),
                Vectorize(function(i,j) max(m[c(i,j)], na.rm = TRUE) -
                                        min(m[c(i,j)], na.rm = TRUE)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    4    5    4    7    5
# [2,]    5    4    4    6    5
# [3,]    4    4    3    6    5
# [4,]    7    6    6    6    7
# [5,]    5    5    5    7    5
```

Comment: Thats it! Works great. Thank you very much. Meanwhile I also found a solution that so far seems to work:`f <- function(x,y) max(x,y, na.rm=TRUE) - min(x,y, na.rm=TRUE)
    maxmin <- dist(t(m), f, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE, pairwise=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's also an alternative solution. Here is the code:

```
require(proxy)
m <- test
d <- dist(t(m), "manhattan", diag=FALSE, upper=TRUE)/nrow(m)
f <- function(x,y) max(x,y, na.rm=TRUE) - min(x,y, na.rm=TRUE)
maxmin <- dist(t(test), f, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE)
RawAgreementWeighted <- as.matrix((-1 * d + maxmin) / maxmin)
diag(RawAgreementWeighted) <- 1
```

Basically I had to create a distance matrix of the max-min values (maxmin) using function f. This can only be done using function "dist" from package "proxy".